# Dynamically fetch a value based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a drop-down menu that allows users to select how low they want to book an item. I am letting `stripe` to handle the payment. I would like to have the `length` retrieved dynamically based on the selection.

```
<%= form_tag pages_next_url(@booking), :length => params[:length] do %>

    <div class="input-field">
      <!--<%= label :length, "How long will you stay?" %>-->
      <%= select_tag "length", options_for_select(@garage_times.map { |obj| [obj['time'], obj['value']] }) %>
    </div>

    <%= hidden_field_tag :garageid, @garage.id %>

    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="<%= Rails.application.secrets.stripe_publishable_key %>"
            data-description="Payment"
            data-amount= <%= garage.weekday*100*length %> <-- need to get length (integer) dynamically 
            data-locale="auto"
            data-email= <%= current_user.email %> ></script>
<% end %>
```

In my controller, I have the values listed. When "1:00 hour" is selected, it should return `length`, `1` for this case, dynamically.

```
@garage_times = [
 {"value" => 1, "time" => "1:00 hour"},
 {"value" => 2, "time" => "2:00 hours"},
 {"value" => 3, "time" => "3:00 hours"},
 {"value" => 4, "time" => "4:00 hours"}
]
```

I understand that it requires AJAX/JS in order to retrieve the value dynamically. I did some research and watched Railscast on their dynamic form. However, it does not help on my case. All of the examples I have seen are retrieving values from a `model`. Also, I know that it can be done if I put the calculation in the controller, but the whole point is to allow users to see the total amount on the pay button when they input their payment information.

Please guide me. I have minimal knowledge of JS and AJAX. Thank you.

Edit:
I am still unable to solve this problem still.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can avoid using AJAX and use the select list `value`. Then use the `length` value to update the button.

You can do something like this in jQuery:

```
$('#length').on('change', function() {
  weekday_rate = $('#weekday_rate').html();
  length = $(this).val();
  $('.stripe-button').attr('data-amount', weekday_rate * 100 * length)
})
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to do in the way you mentioned. `garage.weekday` will return a float value from database (eg 1.50 per hour).  I think it is easier just to retrieve `length` (1, 2, 3 hours) instead of letting jQuery to do the entire calculation.

Comment: Updated answer. You can have the current weekday rate in a hidden div.

Comment: I tried your method and it did not work for my case. I changed the code to `alert` and remove `weekday_rate` to make sure that my JS works. And it did an alert with the correct multiplied value. But it refused to change the `data-amount` for the script. I will report back when I have a working answer for my case.